# How configure TypeORM ormconfig.json file to parse Entities from js dist folder or ts src folder?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I set my TypeORM config entities path like:

```
"entities": ["src/entities/**/*.ts"]
```

This works good when I use ts-node. `ts-node src/main.ts`

After compile typescripts using `tsc`, I got a `dist` folder with the compiled application:

However, typeORM still tries to get entities from the `src` folder instead of `dist`. throwing a lot of unexpectec syntax errors for parsing a TS file instead of a JS. So I change the fallowing string to the entities condiguration:

```
"entities": ["dist/entities/**/*.js"]
```

It works with node `node dist/main.js` but it does not works with `ts-node src/main.ts`

How can I configure `ormconfig.json` to be able to work with both (`node` at `dist` folder and `ts-node` at `src` folder)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd suggest using an [`ormconfig.js`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md#using-ormconfigjs) instead of the JSON version and use an environment variable or similar to switch between the two configs. eg; something like the following stripped down example.

```
const srcConfig = {
  "entities": [
    "src/entities/**/*.ts"
  ],
}

const distConfig = {
  "entities": [
    "dist/entities/**/*.js"
  ],
}

module.exports = process.env.TS_NODE ? srcConfig : distConfig;
```

Note you'll need to set the `TS_NODE` env var somewhere; I did notice [there's a PR](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/pull/858) not yet merged that will do it.

Comment: For the people looking for the linked PR. It has been merged, by including a symbol on the process variable. To branch your code in case you are running with _ts\_node_, you can check if `process[Symbol.for("ts-node.register.instance")]` is _truthy_.

Answer (score 0):

In **addition** to the existing answer:

I didn't like the idea to much to always work on the dist folder. Why? Because when I run commands from the command line I don't want to check whether dist is up-to-date, meaning was recently compiled.

So, I like my my `typeorm` commands like `typeorm schema:sync` work on the `src`! You can do that by running them via `ts-node`.

So, instead of

```
typeorm schema:sync
```

use

```
// Linux
ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm schema:sync

// Windows
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js schema:sync
```

#### Background

typeorm cli uses node, which relies on the files being compiled to javascript. So, that would only work on the /dist folder, which is the compiled version. However, that requires a watcher or similar running to capture changes of your ORM files. The described way here compiles typescript on-the-fly making a compilation not required. Source: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-to-use-typeorm-with-ts-node

Answer (score 0):

Based upon [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5416735/lock) answer:

My full ormconfig.js

```
//npm install --save "detect-ts-node"
const detectTSNode = require('detect-ts-node');

const commonConfig = {
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 1433,
    "username": "sa",
    "password": "$$$$$$",
    "database": "$$$$$$",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "options": {
        "encrypt": false,
        "enableArithAbort": false
    }
};


const srcConfig = {
    "entities": [
        "src/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "src/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
        "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
    }
};

const distConfig = {
    "entities": [
        __dirname +  "/dist/entity/**/*.js"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        __dirname + "/dist/migration/**/*.js"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        __dirname +  "/dist/subscriber/**/*.js"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir": __dirname +  "/dist/entity",
        "migrationsDir": __dirname +  "/dist/migration",
        "subscribersDir": __dirname + "/dist/subscriber"
    }
};


const result = {};
let key;

// Append common configs to final object
for (key in commonConfig) {
    if (commonConfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result[key] = commonConfig[key];
    }
}

if (detectTSNode) {
    // if ts-node append src configuration
    for (key in srcConfig) {
        if (srcConfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = srcConfig[key];
        }
    }
} else {
    // else append dist configuration
    for (key in distConfig) {
        if (distConfig.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            result[key] = distConfig[key];
        }
    }

}


module.exports = result;
```

Usage in console.ts (my main file name)

```
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
const conf = require('../ormconfig.js');

// Print the result for debuggin purposes
console.log(conf);

createConnection(conf).then(async connection => {
   console.log("do your job here")
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```